# fork(), problems with multiple children

Tags: c, fork, parent, semaphore

I edited a little bit :

```
for ( ii = 0; ii < nbEnfants; ++ii) {
    switch (fork()){
        case -1 : {
                    printf("\n\nSoucis avec fork() !!! \n\n");
                    exit(0);
                    };

        case 0 : {
                    EEcrireMp(ii);
                    }break;
        default : {
                    tabPidEnfants[ii] = p;
                    usleep(50000);
                    ELireMp(nbSect, nbEnfants,tabPidEnfants);
                    };
    }
}
```

My problem : i get to many child, like a bomb of children spawning. How can i stop those child ? the break should stop it no ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want the child to do if returned from `EEcrireMp(ii);`? Btw: Your "impression" is correct.

Comment: EEcrireMp(ii) : it's writes on the shared_memory then I do +1 in the sem_value with the flag : IPC_NOWAIT; But I don't do exit() because the child needs to be still running until the parent Read wich is done by ELireMP() thans

Comment: Sry, but I wanted to ask "*What do you want the child to do **when returned from the call** to EEcrireMp()*"; "*... still running ...*" doing **what**?

Comment: when the "EEcrireMp()" is finished I just want that the parent do the 2nd child and this one do the same thing that the 1st child did until the 20th child. And after the 20th I want that the function in the ELireMP is done :)

Comment: You **still did not tell us** what the children should do after they returned from `EEcrireMp()`. From this fact one might get the idea they ought to do nothing. So why not just let them `exit()`?

Comment: ok here is the code for EEcrireMP() : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2013/35/1377946365-sans-titre.png sorry I can't edit my post by adding the code it said there r format error -_-

Comment: "*... because the child needs to be still running until the parent Read ...*" Why?

Comment: Because I need concurency in my program. Is this the way you do right ?

Comment: Why or for what do you **need** concurrency? Also you **do have** concurrency, as you fork off 20 children from the parent, which all  are running concurrently, in parallel.

Comment: I need concurrency because it's asked on the question :) And no I don't have concurency because I do the "exit()" right after the EEcrireMP().

Comment: You do have. I might be a good idea to read a bit more on how `fork()` works.

Comment: However, just replace the `exit()` by a `pause()` ... ;-)

Comment: mmhh nope it still doesn't work if I replace with "pause()" :(

Comment: "*... it still doesn't work ...*" mostly does not help much. "*What1* does not do *what2* but is givning *what3*", would be more helpful.

Comment: well normaly I shoulld have 20 line of result ( 1 line = 1 chid result) but here i got 1 result and after 2/3 seconds I got the 2nd line of result but between the 2 lines there is what should appeared with the ELireMP function. And the second lines appears too many times also. Sorry if I can't be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, when you `fork` a process, the new process is an identical copy of the parent, so when your child continues from the `if ((pid = fork()) == 0) ...`, it will continue out into the for-loop and create more children.

The child should use `exit(0)` when it's finished (or at least NOT continue the `fork`-loop - you could use `break;` to exit the loop for example. Eventually, the child process should `exit` however.

In the OTHER side, if you want to make sure this child is FINISHED before creating the next `fork`, you should use `waitpid()` or some other variant of `wait`. Of course, these will wait for the forked process to exit, so if the forked process doesn't exit, that's not going to work. But you need to have a strategy for how you deal with each process. If you want to have 20 forked processes running at once, then you will probably need to store your `pid` in an array, so you can track the processes later. One way or another, your main process should track and ensure the processes are finished before it finishes itself.

Comment: If I do the "break;", it will kill the child or not ? In fact I need 20 child running at once and when they did there thing I want to kill them all.

Comment: That depends on what the code after the for-loop does. Using `break` won't in itself kill the child process. It will do whatever happens after the for-loop....

Comment: And that could be something like `if (p == 0) ...` which will then do something meaningful in the child-case.

Comment: so if put the break instead of the exi(); it will do the sme thing that with the exit() but the child woulld be stil alive ? So I will have my 20 child running // ?

Comment: ok and where do you put the "break;" ? In the function EEcrireMP() or just after calling this one ? And do you use also the function "free()" to kill the childs or there is an another one ? Thanks :)

Comment: After calling the function. `free()` won't kill the children. They should exit by themselves.